# Ordering ActiveRecord Relation by temporary column field in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I need to order a query of `Profile` entries in an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object by a value that is computed on run-time.

I have created and assigned a temporary column `distance` in my **controller** for the `Relation` object by using `attr_accessor` like so:

```
@profiles.each do |p|
  p.class_eval do
   attr_accessor :distance
  end
end

@profiles.each do |p|
  p.distance = distance_arr[@profiles.index(p)]  # Distance values obtained from an instance array
end
```

However, when I try to order the `Relation` with the order method, I get a `no such column: distance` error i.e. it's not picking up the temporary field.

Here's how I tried to order it in my **controller** (note I'm using the `will_paginate` gem, but that is irrelevant).

```
@profiles = @profiles.order('distance ASC').paginate(page: params[:page])
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315392/order-model-objects-by-an-attr-accessor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've added the distance attribute to the profile instances. So the distance stuff is all in ruby and sql doesn't know anything about it. Since you are calculating the distances in ruby you'll need to order them in ruby. You can make use of the sort_by method.

```
@profiles.sort_by{|p| p.distance}
```

Alternatively you could push the distance calculation into sql. Something like the following

```
@profiles = Profile.select('*, 10 as distance').order('distance')
```

Here you can see the computed distance column has been added to the select which tells active record to change the query.

Comment: The sort_by method works perfectly, thanks! On a side note, to get `will_paginate` working with Array objects, I had to add a require statement http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352895/ruby-on-rails-will-paginate-an-array